# static resolved type parameters expects additional expression

Tags: f#

The following code

```
let inline foo< ^T, ^U when ^T : (member foo : (^U -> ^T) -> ^T -> ^T)> 
    (f:(^U -> ^T)) (t:^T) : ^T = 
    (^T : (member foo : (^U -> ^T) -> ^T -> ^T) f,t )
```

yields this error

```
let inline foo< ^T, ^U when ^T : (member foo : (^U -> ^T) -> ^T -> ^T)> (f:^U) (t:^T) : ^T = (^T : (member foo : (^U -> ^T) -> ^T -> ^T) f,t );;
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

/stdin(45,96): error FS0735: Expected 3 expressions, got 2
```

I really dont get why its expecting 2 expressions?
Can anybody explain *and* come up with a working solution?

thx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, but this works:

```
  let inline foo< ^T, ^U when ^T : (member foo : (^U -> ^T) -> ^T -> ^T)>
    (f:(^U -> ^T)) (t:^T) : ^T =
    (^T : (member foo : (^U -> ^T) -> ^T -> ^T) t, f, t)
```

As I understand it, the first `t` is necessary to extract the foo method from the instance of the `^T` type.

Or maybe you wanted the foo method of the `^T` type to be static. In that case, the following code works:

```
let inline foo2< ^T, ^U when ^T : (static member foo : (^U -> ^T) -> ^T -> ^T)>
  (f:(^U -> ^T)) (t:^T) : ^T =
  (^T : (static member foo : (^U -> ^T) -> ^T -> ^T) f, t)
```

Comment: because of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37855555/how-can-unify-the-signature-of-this-member-method-and-the-inline-function ;-)
But to really answer your question - its an attempt to emulate as much Haskell as possible

Comment: mostly trying to emulate type classes

Comment: @robkuz Then that's definitely the place to go. Have a look at the source code of [FsControl](https://github.com/gmpl/FsControl).