# How can unify the signature of this member method and the inline function

Tags: f#

given this code

```
type Baz = Baz of int with
    static member bar f (Baz(b)) = f b

let inline foo< ^T, ^U when ^T : (static member bar : (^U -> ^T) -> ^T -> ^T)>
    (f:(^U -> ^T)) (t:^T) : ^T = 
    (^T : (static member bar : (^U -> ^T) -> ^T -> ^T) f, t )

let x = foo (fun x -> (Baz 0)) (Baz 1)
```

I get this error

```
error FS0043: Method or object constructor 'bar' not found
```

I assume that signature of my static member can not really be unified to `(^U -> ^T) -> ^T -> ^T`

How can I solve this?

Comment: `Baz.bar` has the type `(int -> 'a) -> Baz -> 'a`, which doesn't fit with `(^U -> ^T) -> ^T -> ^T)`.

Comment: @MarkSeemann yeah I know - however isn't `(^U -> ^T) -> ^T -> ^T` a superset of `(int -> 'a) -> Baz -> 'a`

Comment: Starting from left, if `int` takes the place of `^U`, and `'a` takes the place of `^T`, then the signature ought to be `(int -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'a`, which it isn't... unless there's something I'm missing...

Comment: @MarkSeemann yea so I thought as well and changed the member function to `static member bar (f: 'a -> 'b) (b:'b) : 'b = match b with | Baz(i) -> f i` which yields the following signature `static member bar : f:(int -> Baz) -> b:Baz -> Baz`. So this shoud ultimately be the same as `(^U -> ^T) -> ^T -> ^T` only it isnt :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37854165/static-resolved-type-parameters-expects-additional-expression) (i.e. switching back to the member function) and your comments, perhaps this would work:

```
type Baz = Baz of int with
    member this.bar (f: 'a -> 'b): 'b = match this with
                                        | Baz i ->  f i

let inline foo (f: ^U -> ^T) (t:^T)  = 
    let foo' = (^T : (member bar : (^U -> ^T) -> ^T) (t, f))
    foo'

let x = foo (fun x -> (Baz 0)) (Baz 1)

// This returns Baz 0
printfn "%A" x
```

Comment: The reason for all of this is here ;-) https://gist.github.com/robkuz/6f44af11e26a9f2043083e21a6e4ea31